# Able to write on stdout but not in a file

Tags: linux, macos, streaming, io, tcpdump

I want to keep a trace of the URL I visit, so I use a command line like this:

> tcpdump -ien1 -v -X 'tcp port 80'    |  sed -nl
>   's/^.*0x[0-9a-f]{4}:.{43}(.*)$/\1/p' |perl break.pl |perl -pe
>   's/(GET|POST).(.*?).HTTP/1....Host:.([a-zA-Z._0-9-]*)../"\nBEGURL
>   ".localtime().": $1 http://$3$2\n"/ge' | grep "^BEGURL"

It's working fine, one URL per line.
But if I do

> tcpdump -ien1 -v -X 'tcp port 80'    |  sed -nl
>   's/^.*0x[0-9a-f]{4}:.{43}(.*)$/\1/p' |perl break.pl |perl -pe
>   's/(GET|POST).(.*?).HTTP/1....Host:.([a-zA-Z._0-9-]*)../"\nBEGURL
>   ".localtime().": $1 http://$3$2\n"/ge' | grep "^BEGURL" **>> /tmp/out**

(notice the end >> /tmp/out) Then file is empty!
Do you know why? It's totally illogical for me.

I also tried redirecting stdout and stderr to /tmp/out, it's still empty. The file has write access. I have no idea what it can be. Is there anything else than stdout and stderr??

for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might mean that you've tried this, when you say "I also tried redirecting stdout and stderr to /tmp/out" - but it seems like the most likely problem: so try adding 2>&1 to the end.

If not then to help to debug try adding 2>/dev/null to your first command and see if you still get output.

Also, can you simplify the command for testing? For example, does this work:

```
tcpdump -ien1 -v -X 'tcp port 80' >> /tmp/out
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just a few days ago. Try using the `-w` option, to write the packets to a file.
For more information see `man tcpdump`.